# Why is UrlFetchApp unable to fetch content in this case?

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am hoping to save some files to my Google Drive. But `UrlFetchApp.fetch` wouldn't get any response and would time out. How do I know what is wrong here?

```js
var url = 'https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/exp/voiProductsViewExport.ctl?media=xls&tradeDate=20210702&assetClassId=2&reportType=F&excluded=CEE,CEU,KCB';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

Logger.log(response.getResponseCode())

var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID); // omitting folderID in this snippet
var file = folder.createFile(response.getBlob());
file.setName('file.xls');
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68245674/1595451)

Comment: @Argyll how did you get on with this?

Comment: @iansedano: Still thinking. I might use the tool in your answer and a locally triggered script to open/close it in the browser. Also wonder if anyone else discovers something different with CME's site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It sounds like CME may have blocked Apps Script.

I have seen a few questions like this today.

There is not much you can do about the CME blockage (if that is the case), but there is a way to workaround this, even though it requires visiting a browser. I noticed that if I used the JavaScript `fetch` API, it would return the XLS blob correctly, so here is a workaround using an Apps Script Web App.

#### Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    
  </body>

  <script>
    const r = fetch('https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/exp/voiProductsViewExport.ctl?media=xls&tradeDate=20210702&assetClassId=2&reportType=F&excluded=CEE,CEU,KCB')
    .then(r => r.blob())
    .then(b => readFile(b))
    .then(result => saveToDrive(result))

    function saveToDrive(base64) {
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(() => console.log("success"))
        .saveAsXLS(base64)
    }

    function readFile(blob){
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var fr = new FileReader();  
        fr.onload = () => {
          resolve(fr.result)
        };
        fr.onerror = reject;
        fr.readAsDataURL(blob);
      });
    }

  </script>

</html>
```

#### Code.gs

```js
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index")
}

function saveAsXLS(dataURL){
  const parts = dataURL.split(",")
  const type = (parts[0]).replace('data:','');
  const blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(parts[1], Utilities.Charset.UTF_8), type, "sheet.xls")

  DriveApp.createFile(blob)
}
```

Basically, instead of using UrlFetchApp, it uses a browser instance to use the JavaScript `fetch` API to get the blob, and then encode it before sending it to the Apps Script side. The Apps Script side then decodes it and saves it to Drive.

#### Caveat

Though you might just as well be using `curl` or Python at this point since you have to actially visit the Web App to execute it.

#### Reference

- [Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities)
- [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)